# Many errors after upgrading to Flutter 3.7.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, mobile-development

After upgrading to Flutter 3.7.0 I got many errors when trying to run any app (Project).

The following log is an example from one of my projects

[image]

Can anyone help me solving this problem?

Comment: have you run `flutter pub get` in your project directory? Also, post your output from flutter doctor -v.

Comment: flutter pub get ran smoothly, and flutter doctor no issues found. I downgraded Flutter and these errors no longer appear, but I have to use the latest version

Comment: You can try `flutter pub upgrade` to see if any dependencies need an update after Flutter 3.7.0 update?

Comment: @daan I did it and the same errors apprears

Comment: Too bad, only thing that comes to mind is: `flutter clean` and try to run your project again...

Comment: I also did this with no luck. Also i did invalidate cache and the errors still exist.

Comment: what is your gradle version?

Comment: Gradle version is 6.7